# Create 3D geometry in/from Matlab for PDE analysis

Tags: matlab

Matlab solves 3D PDEs importing STL geometries done in a CAD program and then does the meshing. I was wondering though if (1) it's possible to generate a 3D geometry from inside Matlab as edges/coordinates, or (2) calling a free software that admits the cooordinates, creates the STL, and then Matlab recuperates the model for the usual process. For instance:

[image] or [image]

Matlab can interact with Abaqus and do precisely this, but I'm looking for a simpler way.

Any ideas?
Thanks!